# Where to place tracks in external card

Tags: mp3-player, rockbox, sansa

I have added external 64Gb  card to my  Sansa Clip Zip that runs RockBox. But where to place tracks? There is no any files and directories there should I place to root?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Rockbox manual](http://download.rockbox.org/manual/rockbox-ipodnano2g.pdf), you can place the files anywhere on the file system:

> Files may be placed wherever you like on the player, but it is
>   strongly suggested NOT to put them in the /.rockbox folder and instead
>   put them in any other folder, e.g. /, /music or /audio. The default
>   directory structure that is assumed by some parts of Rockbox (album
>   art searching, and missing-tag fallback in some WPSes) uses the parent
>   directory of a song The Rockbox manual (version rUnversioned
>   directory-180727) Ipod Nano Chapter 3. Quick Start 22 as the Album
>   name, and the parent directory of that folder as the Artist name.
>   WPSes may display information incorrectly if your files are not
>   properly tagged, and you have your music organized in a way different
>   than they assume when attempting to guess the Artist and Album names
>   from your filetree. See section C (page 192) for the requirements for
>   Album Art to work properly. See section B.1 (page 186) for a list of
>   supported audio formats.